# List/count BOBJ reports that use a specific object

Tags: repository, business-objects, universe

Is there a way to count/list the bobj reports from the repository which use a specific object from a universe?

I'm using BOBJ 4.1.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The *database* repository (CMS repository) only contains information regarding what universe is used by what document, but not down to the level of universe objects. The information is locked inside the physical files, stored in the FRS and not thus not readable without using the SDK.

If you need to know the universe objects being used, you'll need to something like [Information Steward](http://www.sap.com/pc/tech/enterprise-information-management/software/data-integrity-steward/index.html), [Sherlock](http://evtechnologies.com/products/sherlock/) or [Infolytik MetaMiner](http://www.infolytik.com). These products leverage the BusinessObjects SDK to look inside of each document and analyse the structure and contents.

An alternative could be to use the Platform Search feature, which you can set up to analyse different levels of your repository, down to the structure and contents of the documents, thus including which universe objects are used.

Platform Search is built upon [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org) technology, so you could use these files to extract the metadata information you need to perform your analysis. A tool like [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) can be used to analyse the Lucene index files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, @Kristof. I knew about the limitations of the repository, hence the question. 

I will look at all the options in your post and come back.